# Constant defined in code but not retrievable through console

Tags: javascript

My code is as follows:

```js
class Rectangle {
  constructor(height, length) {
    this.height = height;
    this.length = length;
  }
  area() {
    return this.height * this.length;
  }
}

const square = new Rectangle(10, 10);

console.log(square);
console.log(square.area());
```

However, my console is showing the following:

[image: Screenshot of console overview.]

I'm trying to understand a few things.

1. Why is the console saying `square` is undefined?
2. Why doesn't the console denote the class of `square` in the log, demoting it to a generic `Object` rather than a `Rectangle`?
3. What processes can I adopt in my workflow to help me answer these questions before asking Stack Overflow?

I've checked my Firefox version and reviewed this on Safari as well, and the problem is the same. Initially, I was using a separate .js file to define a more complicated class, but after more and more simplification, I realized that even this basic case isn't working for me.

I've also noticed that other posts are about the reverse problem: something showing up in console but not in code.

Comment: Your code is working just fine, no problems. regex_list must be for other code as it isn't used in the code provided. And the favicon.ico just means there isn't a favicon.ico file, it isn't a problem.

Comment: Presumably you're not actually _running_ that code in the console, i.e. the `const` is defined in a scope _other than_ the one that's being evaluated when you then type `square` in the console. This is the expected behaviour, `let`/`const` are scoped, not global like `var` - see e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/q/762011/3001761.

Comment: I can't reproduce the error with given code sample, only thing i can think of square is being called somewhere else not shown in the given sample

Comment: For those not understanding the issue. The code in the snippet runs probably in a script as part of a (localhost) website. Then OP types `square` in the JavaScript developer tools console and gets the `ReferenceError`.

Comment: @3limin4tor is correct – Jon Sharpe notes that I'm not running code in the console, but the HTML I'm looking at is associated with a script housing only the above block of code. I'm able to get regular objects without this error – it only comes up when I introduce classes.

Comment: I'm also still concerned about the class of `square` in the console log.

Comment: @cbitt How are you including the code in your html? Is a script or a module?

Comment: @cbitt Can you share the "working" code (without classes) for comparison? Please [edit] your question to include this info

Comment: @jonrsharpe top-level `let` and `const` declarations in a script do introduce global variables just fine, which should be accessible from the console as well. It's only that they do not create properties of the global object, and of course in block scopes they behave differently.

Comment: @Bergi I've been using "module". Tried "script" and saw no difference. The working code is just setting a const and returning that – it worked before, but even now I'm seeing "Uncaught ReferenceError: 'example' is not defined"

Comment: If you mean `<script type="module">`, then yes that's the culprit. All the variables declared in the code are local to that module. Use `window.square = …` to create a global, or just use `<script>` only.

Comment: *I'm also still concerned about the class of `square` in the console log.* - you're running it in [Firefox](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1526688), that's why. In Chrome/Edge you'd see `> Rectangle` (but would not see the fields without "opening" it). But Firefox still correctly lists `area()` and the constructor, so nothing is really lost.